# Can a "discrete" argument involving a gamma mixture of Poisson distributions be adapted to work for non-integers?

Tags: probability-distributions

**PREFACE**

Here I will begin with this preface that is nearly the same as what I wrote in [an earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444904/realizing-a-negative-binomially-distributed-random-variable-simultaneously-in-tw).

Suppose
$$
\Pr(\Lambda\in d\ell) = \frac 1{\Gamma(\alpha)}
\left( \frac\ell m\right)^{\alpha-1} e^{-\ell/m}\, \left( \frac{d\ell} m \right)
\text{ for } \ell>0,
$$
so $\Lambda$ is a random variable with a gamma distribution with expected value $\alpha m$ and variance $\alpha m^2$.

Let the conditional distribution of the random variable $N$, given $\Lambda$, be
$$
N\mid\Lambda \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\Lambda).
$$
Then the marginal (``unconditional'') distribution of $N$ is a negative binomial distribution:
\begin{align*}
& \Pr(N=n) \\[10pt] = {} & \operatorname E(\Pr(N=n\mid\Lambda))
= \operatorname E\left( \frac{\Lambda^n e^{-\Lambda}}{n!} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \tag{$*$} \int_0^\infty \frac{\ell^n e^{-\ell}}{n!}
\cdot \frac1{\Gamma(\alpha)} \left( \frac\ell m\right)^{\alpha-1}
e^{-\ell/m} \, \left( \frac{d\ell} m \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{(n+\alpha-1)(n+\alpha-2)(n+\alpha-3)\cdots\alpha}{n!}
\left( \frac m{m+1} \right)^n \left( \frac1{m+1} \right)^\alpha \\[8pt]
= {} & \binom{-\alpha}{\phantom{-}n} p^\alpha (-q)^n
\text{ for } n\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}
\end{align*}
(so that $p+q=1$), where
$$
\binom{-\alpha}{\phantom{-}n}
= \frac{\overbrace{-\alpha(-\alpha-1)(-\alpha-2)\cdots(-\alpha-n+1)}^\text{$n$ factors}}{n!}.
$$

**END OF PREFACE**

Here I present a different argument to establish the same result. This argument is sound when $\alpha\in\{\,1,2,3,\ldots\,\}.$ My question is whether some small changes could make it work for real $\alpha>0.$

The simplest sort of Poisson process discussed in introductory textbooks assigns a Poisson-distributed random variable to every bounded subinterval of $[0,+\infty)$ (and hence to every measurable subset of $[0,+\infty),$ if you like), and the expected value of each such Poisson-distributed random variable is $m$ times the length of the interval ($m$ is the "rate" or "intensity"), and the Poisson-distributed random variables are independent when the intervals are pairwise (essentially) disjoint. For this process, the waiting time $T_\alpha$ until the $\alpha$th "arrival" is distributed as
$$
\Pr(T\in dt) = \frac1{\Gamma(\alpha)} \left( \frac t m \right)^{\alpha-1} e^{-t/m} \, \left( \frac{dt} m \right) \text{ for } t>0,
$$
a gamma distribution.

And you see that this makes sense only when $\alpha\in\{\,1,2,3,\ldots\,\}.$

Now consider a second Poisson process independent of the first, with rate $n.$  **Consider the probability distribution of the number of arrivals of the second Poisson process before the $\alpha\textbf{th}$ arrival of the first.**

It is well known that for each arrival of the union of the two processes, the probability that it is of the second process is $q = n/(n+m).$

Thus we seek the probability distribution of the number $N$ of "failures" (arrivals of the second process) needed to get $\alpha$ "successes" (arrivals of the first).

This is
\begin{align}
& \Pr(N=n) \\[8pt] = {} & \Pr\left( \begin{array}{l} \text{exactly $n$ failures in the first $n+\alpha-1$ trials} \\ \text{and success on the $(n+\alpha)$th trial} \end{array} \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \binom{n+\alpha-1}{n-1} q^n p^{\alpha-1} \cdot p \qquad \text{where } q=1-p \\[8pt]
= {} & \binom{-\alpha}{\phantom{+}n} p^\alpha (-q)^n.
\end{align}
So that is the value of the integral.

**My question is:** Can this method be somehow adapted so that it can find the value of the integral $(*)$ in the "PREFACE" when $0<\alpha\notin\mathbb\{\,1,2,3,\ldots\,\} \text{?}$